# Завершить lock блокировку по таймауту

Tags: c#, mutex

Необходимо сделать блокировку, ограниченную по времени, например 1 секунду. В теле блокировки я делаю задержку на 2 секунды (умышленно):

1. Начало блокировки с ограничением в 1 секунду
2. Заведомо долгая операция превышающая 1 секунду
3. Конец блокировки

Так вот, можно ли каким то образом, прервать выполнение кода внутри тела блокировки по таймауту (принудительно остановить выполнение пункта 2, завершить блокировку), и выкинуть исключение о превышении таймаута?

Вычитал что в шарпе обычный lock(object) { ... } не имеет таймаута, но, есть: Monitor.TryEnter(object, timeout), который, я так подозреваю, проверяет таймаут на этапе постановки в очередь. (так ли это?)

Отдельно поясню по содержимому тела блокировки (всё то что идёт между lock и unlock вызовами) - это не множество мелких операций, а несколько достаточно продолжительных по времени (сферический пример в вакууме - пара вызовов функции скачивания 10ГиБ файла).

Подскажите, есть готовые механизмы или сахар в шарпе, решающие мою задачу, или, всё же, придётся самостоятельно в отдельном потоке мониторить, и по таймауту принудительно завершать поток? (что значительно увеличит объёмы кода и сложность, казалось бы, такой простой вещи)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049346/how-long-will-a-c-sharp-lock-wait-and-what-if-the-code-crashes-during-the-lockhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049346/how-long-will-a-c-sharp-lock-wait-and-what-if-the-code-crashes-during-the-lock

Comment: @tym32167, я уже упомянул TryEnter в вопросе, и да, примеры с ним - не решают мою задачу

Comment: Есть `Mutex`, который поддерживает таймаут, вроде. Но он "дороже" чем `Monitor` и я не уверен, делает ли он то что вам нужно

Comment: @АндрейNOP, Да, в документации есть примеры с Mutex.WaitOne, но, подозреваю, они ведут себя точно так же как и Monitor.TryEnter: https://pastebin.com/uAwWuSL4 Поток не прекращает спать, и ожидает все 2 секунды (так он может спать все 20 секунд и 1 час, не прерывая операции в теле блокировки), мне же, хотелось посылать сигнал завершения работы потока спустя уже первую секунду, указанную в таймауте.

Comment: Интересно, какого поведения вы ожидаете здесь: https://pastebin.com/uAwWuSL4 ?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, исключение, либо пустую консоль (без сообщений)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этой задачи нет встроенной фишки, а в `Monitor.TryEnter` и в похожих на него методах указывается не время, которое у него есть на работы с заблокированным объектом, а время в течении которого он блокирует текущий поток и пытается получить эту блокировку, если он получает её сразу, то никакой задержки не происходит.
А вашу задачу (если верить сферическому примеру в вакууме), можно реализовать с помощью `Thread.Join` указав ему период времени и завершив поток по его истечении.

Comment: Да, есть такое дело. Тоже подумывал что не совсем корректно вопрос поставил. Скорее всего, тут, действительно, нужно не саму блокировку делать временной, а задачу, которая будет выполняться в блокировке.

Comment: Подожду ещё, может будут другие варианты решения (вариант с потоками мне не очень нравится, потому что для выполнения одной такой задачи нужно создавать два потока, в первом будет задача, второй будет следить за состоянием первого, и в случае необходимости убивать его и себя)

Comment: [Вот тут был задан нужный тебе вопрос :D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout)